# InvalidCastException when casting to Applicaiton class after Mono upgrade

Tags: xamarin.android, monodevelop

I just started up my project in MonoDevelop again after not having looked at it for a few months. Of course there was a new version for Mono, MonoDevelop and Mono for Android.

As soon as I run the app I get a `InvalidCastException` when casting to my `Application` class in one of my activities:

> Error:System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

The line comes from

```
ConferenceApplication conferenceApplication = ((ConferenceApplication)base.Application);
```

When I print the `base.Application.Class` it reports `mono.android.app.Application` and not my own application class. My application class is denoted with `[Application]` and extends `Android.App.Application`.

I'm pretty confident that the app has not been changed since the last time I ran it. What could the cause for this problem be? And how can I fix it?

I'm using the Beta channel for updates.

```
MonoDevelop 3.0.4.7
Mono 2.10.9
Mono for Android: 4.2.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded to latest stable of Mono for Android - **4.2.6** - and it all magically just worked.